# Use IEqualityComparer to generate a distinct list based on two properties in C#

Tags: c#, linq, iequalitycomparer

I am trying to generate a listbox of items that is a concatenation of two strings. I have created a class that implements IEqualityComparer and I want to make this list distinct.

```
private void PopulateFamily()
    {
        var source = _mfgOrdersData
            .Select(o => new FamilySelector(o.ItemWrapper.ItemClass, o.ItemWrapper.Family))
            .Distinct()
            .OrderBy(f => f.CodeFamily)
            .ToList();

        FamilyFilterListBox.DataSource = source;
        FamilyFilterListBox.ValueMember = "Family";
        FamilyFilterListBox.DisplayMember = "CodeFamily";
    }

class FamilySelector : IEqualityComparer<FamilySelector>
{
    public FamilySelector(string code, string family)
    {
        Code = code;
        Family = family;
    }

    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Family { get; set; }
    public string CodeFamily { get { return string.Format("{0}\t{1}", Code, Family); } }

    public bool Equals(FamilySelector x, FamilySelector y)
    {
        return x.Code == y.Code && x.Family == y.Family;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(FamilySelector obj)
    {
        return obj.Code.GetHashCode() ^ obj.Family.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

The problem is that I am getting the list non distinct. The same item appears multiple times.
I presume that Equals() or GetHashCode() are not implemented correctly.

Comment: If Implementing the IEqualityComparer proves difficult, there is another way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/491832/8155

Comment: `IEqualityComparer<T>` is for a class whose role is to do the comparing. You'd have to pass one as the argument to `Distinct`. `IEquatable<T>` on the other hand, is for a class whose instances can be compared for equality. If you change your class to implement `IEquatable<FamilySelector>` instead, the implementation of `Distinct` (which will use `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` which in turn sees your type implements IEquatable and delegates to that) will work as you expect.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 Your comment is the correct answer btw. OP just messed up the interface they need to implement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently you run `Distinct()` on a collection of `FamilySelector` instances which results to comparing by reference equality.

To do it right, you should pass an instance of `IEqualityComparer` to `Distinct()` call:

```
var source = _mfgOrdersData
    .Select(o => new FamilySelector(o.ItemWrapper.ItemClass, o.ItemWrapper.Family))
    .Distinct(new FamilySelector())
    .OrderBy(f => f.CodeFamily)
    .ToList();
```

You should add parameterless constructor to `FamilySelector` class so that code could be compiled.

I'd also suggest small refactoring of `FamilySelector` class. Currently it holds the data and performs comparison. Usually implementation of IEqualityComparer is a data-less class that just performs a comparison:

```
class FamilyData
{
    public FamilyData(string code, string family)
    {
        Code = code;
        Family = family;
    }

    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Family { get; set; }
    public string CodeFamily { get { return string.Format("{0}\t{1}", Code, Family); } }
}

class FamilySelector : IEqualityComparer<FamilyData>
{
    public bool Equals(FamilyData x, FamilyData y)
    {
        return x.Code == y.Code && x.Family == y.Family;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(FamilyData obj)
    {
        return obj.Code.GetHashCode() ^ obj.Family.GetHashCode();
    }
}

var source = _mfgOrdersData
    .Select(o => new FamilyData(o.ItemWrapper.ItemClass, o.ItemWrapper.Family))
    .Distinct(new FamilySelector())
    .OrderBy(f => f.CodeFamily)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Or make it implement `IEquatable<FamilySelector>` instead

Comment: Correct, that's another way to go.

Answer (score 2):

CodeFuller's answer will work fine, but as an alternative option, you could use [MoreLINQ](http://morelinq.github.io/) and its `DistinctBy` method, which would avoid you needing to create a separate class at all:

```
private void PopulateFamily()
{
    var source = _mfgOrdersData
        .Select(o => o.ItemWrapper)
        .DistinctBy(o => new { o.ItemClass, o.Family })
        .OrderBy(f => f.CodeFamily)
        .ToList();

    FamilyFilterListBox.DataSource = source;
    FamilyFilterListBox.ValueMember = "Family";
    FamilyFilterListBox.DisplayMember = "CodeFamily";
}
```

I've assumed that you want to select `ItemWrapper` - it's hard to tell without seeing the types involved, but that looks likely to be what you want.